# How to communicate with different view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a VC that presents another VC modally.  This 2nd VC pushes to a 3rd VC.  The 3rd VC dismisses itself and needs to call a method on the initial VC.  I can't seem to get this working.  Any advice?

```
 VC3 *aVC3 = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] parentViewController];
 aVC3 = self.name;
 [aVC3 addExercise];
 [self dismissView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `delegate` for `backward messsaging`.

Refer [simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development](http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/). Also refer [the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

If you have `UINavigationController` there is `no need of delegate` to communicate to any viewController in navigationController like:

```
ViewController *objViewController = (ViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; //need to which controller u would like to communicate
[objViewController yourMethodHere]; // your method here
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you look at my example.  There is one VC which presents a NavController modally.  So I can get from VC3 back to VC2, but how can I get from VC2 (modal) to VC1?

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternate method:

Step 1: Create a `FirstViewController` Property in the `SecondViewController.h`

```
@interface SecondaryViewController : UIViewController{
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstViewController *viewControllerOne;
```

Step 2: set that property to `self` when presenting the `SecondViewController` in `FirstViewController.m`

```
@implementation SecondaryViewController

-(void)functionThatPresentsSecondViewController{
    SecondViewController *viewControllerTwo = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    [viewControllerTwo setViewControllerOne: self];
    [self presentViewController:viewControllerTwo animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Step 3: You can now call `FirstViewController` functions from `SecondViewController` by using the `viewControllerTwo.viewControllerOne` property.

Comment: There are 3 VCs in my example.

Comment: Your view controllers shouldn't know about each other like that. That is creating a dependency between them so if you then remove or change one of the VCs then you have to change others. See the answer by Prince regarding delegates.